# HTTP GET Requests for Beginners - Octoprint

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, request, octoprint

I'm doing a personal project with 3D printing and octoprint, in which I'm trying to retrieve values from the web interface such as the time left for the 3D print to be finished. I've done research and it seems that I have to do an HTTP GET Request. I have done research into the software of octoprint and found that they have an API [documentation](http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/api/index.html). Also, there is an API key to access my specific instance of octoprint. The problem I'm having is that I've never programmed anything with requests. I've done basic javascript, but nothing too advance. I'm looking for someone to guide me in the right direction in making a request and pulling values from the web interface. Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can use express framework. you can get it here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/express

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation to [retrieve your API key](http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/api/general.html#authorization).

From here getting started with `fetch` is the way to go. This is untested code for [getting the API version](http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/api/version.html#get--api-version) but should be close:

```
   const response = await fetch('http://your-device-url/api/version', {
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'X-Api-Key': 'your key goes here'
     }
   });
   const json = await response.json();
   console.log('here is the version information', json);
```

Here are some links to learn more about `fetch`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
https://javascript.info/fetch
https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/fetch-api-introduction-to-promised-based-data-fetching-in-plain-javascript-620e54898d8e

Async functions are a related topic and another thing you'll want to learn.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions